# PostSharp PSSLN gives "Unexpected XML element: LoggingProfiles"

Tags: postsharp

When using PSSLN file, I get the following error in TFS MSBUILD. How do I fix it? The project builds in VisualStudio.

Here is the snippet from TFS build log
Windows\NewProject.pssln (4, 4) Unexpected XML element: LoggingProfiles.
Windows\packages\PostSharp.5.0.29\build\PostSharp.targets (329, 5)
The process C:\ProgramData\PostSharp\5.0.29\bin.Release\postsharp-net40-x86-native.exe exited with code 11

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce this. Could you please share a sample project reproducing this issue?

Comment: It seems not to be an issue with TFS integration. I reproduced the issue in VisualStudio.I had a solution in which one of the project had Postsharp Model. This project had complained about unknown xml element for Logging in pssln. After adding postsharp diagnostics to that project, the build succeeded. Is there a dependency between model, diagnostics & pssln?

Answer (score 1):

PostSharp 5.0 logging is a complete rewrite of the log aspect.
Please refer to their [documentation](http://doc.postsharp.net/logging-upgrade) regarding this, in particular, check out [Customizing the Appearance of Log Records](http://doc.postsharp.net/logging-customizing).

More specifically, `LoggingProfiles` was replaced with `Logging` as you can see in the quote below. Also, I'd suggest using `postsharp.config` instead of the old pssln file, although based on the documentation it *should* work as well.

> ```
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
> <Project xmlns="http://schemas.postsharp.org/1.0/configuration">
>   <Logging xmlns="clr-namespace:PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics;assembly:PostSharp.Patterns.Diagnostics">
>     <Profiles>
>       <LoggingProfile Name="Default" IncludeSourceLineInfo="True">
>         <DefaultOptions>
>           <LoggingOptions IncludeParameterType="True"/>
>         </DefaultOptions>
>       </LoggingProfile>
>     </Profiles>
>   </Logging>
> </Project>
> ```

Good luck.